# Monitor adjust the brightness by itself

Tags: windows, display, lcd, brightness

Below my monitor (LCD screen), there are buttons for changing the luminance of the screen. It only can be adjusted from there. But I don't know starting from when my monitor change the luminance by itself!!! The luminance UI appears on my screen and increase by number, when I manually press the button to decrease the brightness, it again increase by itself! And the worst thing is, my screen becomes darker and darker even though I increase the luminance to 100%...

Could someone help me about this, am I being "watched" by hacker or my monitor is sick...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: this could beaproblem with the backlight.

Comment: Does the monitor OSD (on screen display)  or luminance UI appear when the level is being decreased.or increased By Itself also? That would indicate that a switch on the monitor is stuck down, or making a connection due to a liquid spill .